# Properly sanitize an input field "Name <test@example.com>"

Tags: sanitization

In my plugin I want administrators to be able to set the from name and email address in a single form field.

I anticipate the field content to be `Name <test@example.com>` However both `sanitize_text_field()` and `sanitize_email()` do their jobs and remove critical parts of the data.

Is there better way to do it rather than `wp_kses()`?

Comment: This isn't a better way, but if you must use a single field, and that the value will always be in that format, then you can split the value into 2 parts - the name and email address - then sanitize them separately.

Comment: Or you can use JavaScript to split the data and put them into hidden fields, then at the server-side, it'd be easy to sanitize the values before doing anything else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```php
$input = 'Name <test@example.com>';

// Break the input into parts
preg_match( '/([^<]+)<([^>]+)>/i', $input, $matches, PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL );

// Clean the name
$name = sanitize_text_field( $matches[ 1 ] );

// Clean the email
$email = sanitize_email( $matches[ 2 ] );

// Bail early if the values are invalid.
if ( !$name || !$email || !is_email( $email ) ) {
    die( 'Invalid input' );
}

// Success!
$cleaned_input = "{$name} <{$email}>";
```